# tools to simplify IPC in Electron

Tags: electron, nwjs

Are their any tools for simplifying IPC and doing data marshaling between a single web page and the node.js processes?

I have read: http://tangiblejs.com/posts/nw-js-and-electron-compared-2016-edition

Which overviews the differences between nw.js and electron. Both seem pretty much the same, but I like to minimize complexity when not needed, so I am leaning to nw.js to avoid the issues of IPC.

But this might be a mistake, since I see 10X more comments dealing with electron in this group as opposed to NW.JS

(My IDE will be Visual Studio Code, which now has an extension for NW.JS debug, but none for Electron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We started using NWJS for that reason and also because it had support for `chrome.serial`. Lately I converted the project to electron for a few reasons:

- More large companies on board

  - more commits, testing and maintenance
- More built-in functionality

  - eg, [block power save](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/power-save-blocker/)
- [Better packaging tooling](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/)
- [Better test tooling](http://electron.atom.io/spectron/)

You're right that NWJS doesn't have the complication of the main/render processes but I've found very few reasons to have to deal with IPC.

Many of the APIs are only available in the **main** process but can be accessed via the [remote](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/) API. So for example to get access to the **main** `process.argv` from the **render** process I use:

```
{process} = require('electron').remote
process.argv ...
```

In my index.js I've had to do a few IPC things but electron has libraries to simplify this:

```
// ensure we only have a single instance, but pass args to renderer to open any files passed by explorer
const shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance((argv, workingDir) => {
  win.webContents.send('open-instance', argv);
})
```

Then in my renderer code somewhere I have the following:

```
ipcRenderer.on('open-instance', (event, arg) => {
  this.restoreAndFocus();
  // TODO - handle another instance opening a file from explorer
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Have you seen any good workflows for debug? I tend to prefer vscode as my IDE. I see in the docs about debug of the main proc. But for the render process which will have react and redux, what do you suggest?

Comment: I'm using vscode too. Install the `Debugger for Chrome` extension and here is my launch.json: https://gist.github.com/timfish/d88fc03a221514bfe5de811eff8861c4 You'll probably have to mess around with the paths to get sourcemaps working for your setup. For me breakpoints and debugging is working in TypeScript sources!

Comment: The above is for debugging the render process only. My main process code is so short that I haven't had to debug it.... yet